# Greedy Algorithm: The Robot

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, greedy

Any ideas? I've tried drawing it out and I've narrowed down the minimum number of robots you'd need but I just don't know how to express it in a greedy algorithm or how to prove it. It's a bonus question from one of our lectures so we don't have to know how to do it but I feel like its a good exercise. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Counterexample: 00=start, 23=finish, coins at: 10,01,02,03,12,22

Comment: If the robot starts in the upper-left and walks to the bottom-left, and it can't move left, then it can only go down. I think that second restriction should say that the robot walks to the bottom *right* corner.

Comment: Does the robot know the locations of the coins, or does it just "trip over" coins in its walk? In any case, you need at most 8 robots: the first starts at 0,0 and moves right to the edge, then down. The next starts at 0,0, moves down one row, then right to the edge, and then down. Next moves down two rows, etc. If the robot can look ahead, then the worst case number of robots is the minimum of (occupied rows, occupied columns). That is, if only 2 rows contain coins, then you only need 2 robots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
until robot is at the bottom row:
    while there's a coin to the right on the same row:
        go right
    go down one step
go to the right corner
```

or perhaps more succinctly:

```
If there are coins to the right: go right
Otherwise: go down
```

Edit: 
To see that the algorithm is optimal in the sense that it requires the fewest total number of robots to clear the board, observe that no robot ever makes a move that is worse than an optimal robot: "greedy stays ahead". Here's an attempt to make this argument more formal:

Let G be the greedy algorithm and R be any optimal algorithm.

From the perspective of a single robot, there is some set S of coins within reach. From the starting position, for example, all coins are within reach (though some coins may be mutually exclusive, of course). when a robot r makes a move, a subset V of S becomes unreachable for r. It is clear that for any single move, only one additional robot is needed to take all coins in V. Thus in some sense, the worst possible individual move will be such that V is not empty, and there is no way that a single move would cause the algorithm to require two or more additional robots.

For a robot in G, unless S is empty, V is always a true subset of S. In other words, G doesn't make any "obviously stupid" moves. Combined with the fact that G and R collect all coins, we see that the only interesting places where the robots differ are where they make different choices (down or right) after having taken the same coin.

Consider the robots r in R and g in G at a point where they differ. There are two possibilities:

1. g goes right and r goes down.
2. g goes down and r goes right.

In the first case, there is a coin to the right, and r goes down. Thus V is not empty for r at that step, and by the previous argument, g's decision can't be worse.

In the second case, there is no coin to the right, and g goes down. It is clear that V is empty for g, and r's decision can't be better than that.

We see that in any case where R and G differ, G is at least as good as R, which is optimal, so G must also be optimal.

Comment: Wasn't me. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I just don't know how to express it in a greedy algorithm

Use [Manhattan/taxicab distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)

Then a greedy heuristic may be

- for any robot:

  1. look right-down for the closest coin (using taxicab dist `min(deltaX, deltaY)`)
  2. collect it
  3. from the current point, repeat from step 1.

Just "retire" a robot which see no coins at step 1.

Comment: This is nice, probably more intuitive than my answer. Possibly also easier to prove optimality. Need to always break ties the same way though, otherwise it may not be optimal. If the first robot does this it is not optimal: https://i.imgur.com/UmrBJIM.png

Answer (score 0):

The distance use Manhattan distance.

```
While robot cannot move:
    if robot is at right edge:
        nextStep = down
    if robot is at bottom edge:
        nextStep = right
    nextStep = F(right,down)

F(right,down):
    if(distanceAll(right)<distanceAll(down))
        return right
    else return down

distanceAll(location):
    return the sum of distance between this location to remaining coins
```

distanceAll can be a heuristics function, maybe you can define a range to calculate the sum of distance. 5X5 or 3X3